# How do I deactivate a MutationsObserver after n seconds?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, observable

I'm writing a `generator` function (wrapped w/ a wrapper from the `co` library, allowing me to `yield` to `Promises`, a la `async await`).

The script calls `button.click()` on a DOM Node, then waits for a popup to appear using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which I've wrapped in a `promise`:

```
const startDOMObservable = (domNode) => {

 return new Promise((resolve) => {

        let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, obs) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
               obs.disconnect()
               resolve(mutations, obs)
            })
        })
        observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true })
    })
}
```

In the invoker, ie, the `generator`, I call this function like so:

```
document.querySelector('.the_button').click()
const mutations = yield startDOMObservable(
   document.querySelector('.parent_of_popup')
)
```

(*ETA: this generator/promise pattern may look a little strange, but it works (so far, i think). h/t to [David Walsh blog](https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators) for writing about it*)

Since the generator function that calls `startDOMObservable` is `yield`ing, how do I handle instances where no mutation occurs?  When that happens, I'd like to `resolve` or `reject` the promise w/ an appropriate message.

Comment: _"Since the generator function that calls startDOMObservable is yielding, how do I handle instances where no mutation occurs?"_ Not certain gather logic correctly. You currently `yield` the `Promise` only when a mutation occurs?

Comment: @guest271314 - I didn't really get it either, but from what I could gather, it sounds like the regular functions are turned into generators wich yield, but how that works, and how it would be called again, without any `next` calls or iterators, and how the promise would work in an async/await pattern, is beyond me, I just assumed the OP's code worked the way it was written?

Comment: that's right, @guest271314. i followed [this tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators) for the pattern.  `generator` starts, hits a `yield` of a `function` that returns a `promise`, and waits till a `resolve/reject`.  i struggled to find a way to execute the "click button, wait for popup, scrape popup" pattern w/ the `mutation observable`, and this worked pretty well. if it's not off-topic, is there a more simple way?  and @adeneo is right, the pattern doesn't use the standard `next` or iterators of generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd add the timeout and disconnect the observer after `n` seconds, and then also resolve or reject

```
const startDOMObservable = (domNode, secs) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, obs) {
            obs.disconnect();
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            resolve(mutations, obs);
        });

        observer.observe(domNode, {
            childList: true
        });

        let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            observer.disconnect();
            reject('Nothing happened ?');
        }, secs * 1000);
    })
}
```

and then

```
const mutations = yield startDOMObservable(
   document.querySelector('.parent_of_popup'), 2 // <- seconds to wait
)

document.querySelector('.the_button').click()
```

Comment: will `setTimeout` block the thread? ie, will the rest of the app be able to function? I'm running a few similar processes parallel w/ this one.

Comment: No, `setTimeout` is not blocking

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. to confirm though, `setTimeout` is in `ms` not `s` yea?

Comment: Yeah, definitely needs a `* 1000` on that `setTimeout`.

Comment: i made the edit real quick.  @adeneo, one more clarification: if the `promise resolves()`s normal, but the `timeout` has started, what happens when the time limit (ie, `sec` seconds) is reached?

Comment: Well, it would still reject, but after the resolve. You could just clear that timeout if hits the resolve